# Rails: Reasonable to deploy to both internal server AND Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

Considering migrating an app to Heroku. Currently we build & test locally before deploying to our own server for hosting...But the application is growing and now wondering if it's reasonable to have, say, 3 versions of our app. One local to developer's machines. A second (testing) deployed via Capistrano to an internal server. And then finally a third on Heroku (production). Databases would not need to be shared.

Any problems or advice for this sort of scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a good thing to have a staging server with the same environment as your production. So instead of internal server, wouldn't it be better to test on heroku?

For this purpose I've created another app on heroku and before updating my production app, I push my app to the staging one.

I would highly recommend the [heroku_san](https://github.com/fastestforward/heroku_san) gem which simplifies pushing app to heroku to just `rake staging deploy`.

Answer (score 1):

I do this.  I have development on developer's machines, staging, and production.

Staging is our test sandbox and sometimes also shares user databases with production so I can let users beta test, etc.

Whether or not you use Heroku for production really doesn't matter does it?

Comment: No, Heroku doesn't matter at all actually, and might not even materialize. But we are finding need for a staging server...so I just wanted to verify I wasn't overlooking something about the "Rails way"